# Objective-c How properly mange multiple views and controllers

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, view, structure

I have an aplication which initially there's a TabBarController, each tab is a ViewController and every one has a button which calls other controllers.

So how am I supose to structure this? Having one main rootviewController (if so, how?)? Or calling in the appdelegate only the tabBarController and in each the viewControllers inside the tab call the other controllers?

What's the best way so I can advance, go back and transition views nimbly?

Don't know if I made myself clear...

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you will start with the Template  called "Tab Bar Application" and as of Xcode 4 starts by loading the MainWindow Nib, which hold a tab bar and the tab bar is set up in IB to have 2 view controllers, called "FirstViewController", and "SecondViewController"...

You can follow that pattern if it suites you, otherwise you may want to start with a view based application and add your own tab bar. I personally find it to be easier to control the tab bar, through the `UITabBarDelegate`, especially if you plan to do anything slightly esoteric.

**Edit:**

Basically one of two ways, if you plan to load a Navigation controller stack, or a single modal view.

1)

```
ThirdViewController * controller = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController * myNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];

[self presentModalViewController:myNavigationController animated:YES];
[controller release];
[myNavigationController release];
```

2)

```
ThirdViewController * controller = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];
```

either way get back to the Tab environment by calling the following on the view controller that is calling present modal.

> [self
>   dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: If you had to transtition from the first or secondviewController to another controller where would you call it? In the rootTabBarController?

Comment: you programmatically want to switch from one to two, based on something... say a button press? set the selectedViewController property.

Comment: But for example, imagine I have a TabBarController, there are tabs which are named AViewController, BViewcontroller and CViewController. If I want for instance that when i touch a button in AViewController to show another view what's the best way to do so? Calling the view inside AViewController or sending a selector to the root TabBarController and calling it there? By the way, i read that I should never subclass a UITabBarController, how am I suspose to do it?